# Conditional link_to do block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Maybe this is simpler than I think, but I am having issues getting this to work. I have a link_to block

```
<%= link_to(@animal.previous_animal, {class: 'prev-page'}) do
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> Meet <span class="name"><%= @animal.previous_animal.name %></span>, the <%= animal_breed(@animal.previous_animal) %>
<% end %>
```

But I only want to show the link if a previous_animal exists

```
def previous_animal
 animal = self.class.order('created_at desc').where('created_at < ?', self.created_at)
 animal.last if animal
end
```

Normally within a link_to i could just do

```
<%= link_to(@animal.previous_animal) if @animal.previous_animal %>
```

But I am getting undefined method 'name' when I add the if clause, so it's still running <%= @animal.previous_animal.name %>, even though I thought it was within the if statement?

```
<%= link_to(@animal.previous_animal, {class: 'prev-page'}) if @animal.previous_animal do
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> Meet <span class="name"><%= @animal.previous_animal.name %></span>, the <%= animal_breed(@animal.previous_animal) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You should define `@animal`, `@previous_animal` and `@next_animal` in the controller.  Then your logic can just query those variables.  You might be able to load them in one hit too.

Comment: like @previous_animal = Animal.previous_animal ? as an example

Comment: `@previous_animal = @animal.previous_animal`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% if @animal.previous_animal %>
  <%= link_to(@animal.previous_animal, class: 'prev-page') do %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> Meet <span class="name"><%= @animal.previous_animal.name %></span>, the <%= animal_breed(@animal.previous_animal) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thanks, i tried this earlier but no joy, hence why i have put this question up, thought i was going mad..., must have had a typo, anyway all working

Answer (score 0):

Your link_to if blocks are confusing, and it's causing you problems because you're rendering out the contents even if there's no record.  I would do this:

```
#controller
@animal = Animal.find_by_id(params[:id])
@previous_animal = @animal && @animal.previous_animal
@next_animal = @animal && @animal.next_animal

#view
<% if @previous_animal %>
  <%= link_to(@previous_animal, {class: 'prev-page'}) do
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> Meet <span class="name"><%= @previous_animal.name %></span>, the <%= animal_breed(@previous_animal) %>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <!-- anything you might want to render if there's no previous animal -->
<% end %>
```

Also your previous_animal method can be tidied up a bit.

```
#model
def previous_animal
  Animal.order('created_at desc').where('created_at < ?', self.created_at).first
end

def previous_animal
  Animal.order('created_at').where('created_at > ?', self.created_at).first
end
```